# something to do with fermat's theorem

Tags: number-theory

If $n$ is not a multiple of $23$ then the remainder when $n^{11}$ is divided by $23$ is $1(mod23)$ or $-1(mod23)$.

Now we have $n^{22}=1(mod23) $ which gives $(n^{11})^2=1(mod23)$. From here how can I conclude the result?

Answer (score 1):

The factorization $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ holds for all $x$, in particular with $x=n^{11}$. It follows that $23$ divides $(n^{11}-1)(n^{11}+1)$. Since $23$ is prime, it divides one of these two factors.